# Deprecated lambda capture in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

As proposed in the paper [P0409R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0409r2.html)

I am expecting the definition of x to be deprecated from C++20 and fail to compile but it seems to work in g++ (GCC) 8.1.0 does anyone know if I am doing anything wrong?

In Visual Studio 2017 is fails to compiler with an error around the definition of y.
error C3791: 'this' cannot be explicitly captured when the default capture mode is by copy (=)

<kbd>**[Live Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77207033b605f8cf)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

struct  X {
    void  f()
    {
        int  value = 3;

        auto  x = [=] {         // Deprecated from C++20: 
            return  value + g(); 
        };

        auto  y = [=, this] {   // Recommended method from C++20: 
            return  value + g();  // [=] The this pointer will not be captured, so capture with specifying this 
        };
    }

    int g() const
    {
        return  2;
    }
};

int  main()
{
    X().f();
}
```

Comment: "*In Visual Studio 2017*" Which version of VS2017?

Comment: Wow, that proposal's the very definition of bikeshedding! Stuff like that is why basic operations on the newer language fundamentals keeps changing almost annually. Stop it!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, we should totally stop trying to make the langauge better and more easily digestible by removing confusing ideas like the way `[=]` is supposed to mean "capture by value" but doesn't actually capture members by value because `this` is captured by pointer. The many, many times this has bitten people in the past should not be taken as evidence that the current default is wrong, and we should just live with having to explain to people that "capture by value" doesn't always capture by value.

Comment: @NicolBolas Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27025.1 also known as Visual Studio 15.9.4

Comment: So in that case will a proposal like this just be ignored even when it has been implemented in gcc?

Comment: @Damian: I did some checking, and `[=, this]` is a C++20 feature. Why would you expect a C++17 compiler to compile it?

Comment: @NicolBolas I used the ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest) compiler flag. But then again no guarantee that this would work as you say ;-)

Comment: @NicolBolas What's done is done :P (Well, apparently not, but..!)

Answer (score 6):

A proposal doesn't mean adoption. That said, reading through the wording and the example, it states:

```
 [=, this]{ };      // OK, equivalent to [=]
```

Which seems to indicate that `x` is allowed. I also don't see explicit mention of this being deprecated. It even mentions the opposite:

> We will not consider deprecation in the following survey, since we are only interested in exploring the long-term direction, and deprecation without direction is not all that interesting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all that is just a proposal, doesn't automatically mean it will be part of the standard. Second, C++20 is still in the works.

Now, even if the proposal was adopted in C++20 and even if compilers implemented it, it explicitly says that it doesn't propose deprecation of the old way:

> We will not consider deprecation in the following survey, since we are
>   only interested in exploring the long-term direction, and deprecation
>   without direction is not all that interesting.

Ok, it looks like it will be indeed deprecated in C++20. But again, as the C++20 standard is't final yet, compilers are implementing it as they go, so gcc hasn't implemented this yet.

As for VS, it looks like the 2017 version hasn't implemented the C++17 capture-this-by-value.

Comment: thank you! I think the push these days is to cleanup old code feature, and make it easier to program C++, but I guess to can just join one of the iso meetups. LOL

Comment: @Damian afaik C++ strives with all its might to hold on to backwards compatibility. Features are seldomly deprecated and removed.

Comment: Impliclt capture of `this` by `[=]` is deprecated. See [\[depr.capture.this\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr#capture.this). (I suggest to read the whole annex, to see how many things are deprecated in C++20.)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that [the paper ended up being approved](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0806r2.html). Your sample code produces different warnings when compiling in C++ 20 mode. E.g., with GCC 10:

```
$ g++-10 -c -std=gnu++20 -Wall -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:8:19: warning: implicit capture of ‘this’ via ‘[=]’ is deprecated in C++20 [-Wdeprecated]
    8 |         auto  x = [=] {         // Deprecated from C++20:
      |                   ^
main.cpp:8:19: note: add explicit ‘this’ or ‘*this’ capture
```

If I change the switch, the warning is elsewhere:

```
$ g++-10 -c -std=gnu++1z -Wall -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In member function ‘void X::f()’:
main.cpp:12:23: warning: explicit by-copy capture of ‘this’ redundant with by-copy capture default
   12 |         auto  y = [=, this] {   // Recommended method from C++20:
      |                       ^~~~
```

Comment: Note the phrasing of the warning in C++17 mode: it was once considered a by-value capture of `this` (and so compatible with `[=]` and sort of with `[&]`), but now it is considered to be `*this` that is captured by value (except with `[=]`!) or by reference.

Comment: I found it confusing that they offered two suggestions "add explicitly 'this' or '*this'". Unless I'm missing something, 'this' preserves the original capture behavior, while '*this' doesn't. Seems like they should only suggest changing to 'this'.